# Reports won't save as dashlets

Tags: permissions, reports

I cannot save Reports to Dashlets. I have taken a Membership Detail report and edited it to show me the information I want. I go to the Access tab and click on "Available for dashboard?" and Save it, but nothing happens.There is no dashlet when I go to my dashboard and configure. I have also tried to save it to My Reports and nothing is there.

This WAS working. I had a Membership dashlet and a report of my own in the dropdown report menu. The dashlet stopped working and the report instance has disappeared.

I am on the latest version of CiviCRM 4.7.30

I am logged in as the Super User, I have read the documentation and searched the forum for an answer. As a result, I have specifically created an Admin group to include Super User and given it the Administrator ACL. This account has the Super User privs of Joomla.

I have searched this forum and seen the previous query. I noticed that I do NOT get the ACL and Permissions on my Report instance and never did. Why is that?

Why is nothing happening? What could have changed in the last month?

[image: Access and Save Report has no ACL or Permissions]